# I am unable to export my redcap data and receiving an error notification. notification says to much data although it is a tiny project. solutions?

Tags: export, redcap

**The problem** I am trying to export my redcap data to a CSV form, and unable to do so. I am receiving an error notification that says there is to much data, although it is a tiny project. help will be much appreciated.

**The full error text:** " We are sorry, but apparently the data export is not able to complete successfully. It may simply be that there is too much data trying to be exported at once, in which it is causing REDCap to crash. If this error occurs again, it is recommended that you attempt to export a smaller data set (fewer fields and/or perhaps fewer records) so that this error does not occur. Our apologies for this inconvenience."

**what I have tried**

1. I have made sure I have the necessary user rights.
2. I have tried through a colleges redcap user (who has thenecessary user rights) .
3. have tried exporting only one instrument (no success)
4. have created a test project with only 2 questions. also in the new test project I receive the same notification.
5. could not export data both in development mode and in production.

any ideas?
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The institution had blocked the option for file upload due to security reasons.  Apparently REDCap's exporting system uses the uploading mechanism, and therefore landed up being disabled as well.

Answer (score 0):

The local storage folder location was pointing to a folder that was missing on the server. Just created the folder and upload and subsequent problem was fixed